# How to detect any key press with the keyboard module?

Tags: python

I want to make something so whenever you press any key, it will type something else.

I have tried to make a list of all letters but that didnt work

I want to use this command

```
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a')
        print(list(text[1]))
```

but i want it to work like this

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('any key')
```

Comment: I guess read_hotkey() and read_key() look promising. https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.read_key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the doceument that palvarez recommended because the answer is in there.

I have done it here for you:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.read_hotkey():
        print("you have pressed a key")
```